# How can I get a DataSet as the result of a query in Entity Framework 5.0?

Tags: .net, sql, database, entity-framework, dataset

I'm not sure if this is even possible.  I might be trying to use the wrong tool for the job I'm trying to do.

Suppose that I want to do the following:

I execute a function called "GetTableName" that returns the name of a SQL table I want to get data from.

I execute another function called "GetFields" that returns a the names of one or more fields in the SQL table.

I would like to be able to write another function that would return a DataSet (or some other generic object) containing rows from the table specified by "GetTableName" with the fields specified by "GetFields"

I know that I can do this with the old ADO.net interface, but is there an appropriate way to do this with Entity Framework?

To emphasize, the code will *not* know at compile time what the shape of the data returned from SQL will be.

Comment: Why not just use ADO?  If EF does not know the table definition at design time then why use EF?

Comment: Even if I don't want to use the actual entity classes, I've found it is also very useful for the way it handles connections and everything else for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since EF requires complex types to map onto, it's probably possible to write a class inheriting from ExpandoObject which you would then be able (with alot of coding) to map onto a DataTable class or just use as is. Then you'd basically need to tell EF to somehow try map to those properties.
However, I think that would be a long and winding journey of code, overloads and basicly rewriting the core functionality of EF:s object mapping.

As you can see in this example, where the writer dynamicly creates the model, the hard still remains; the part where you automaticly generate the properties based on the data:
http://www.markzhou.com/blog/post/2011/06/02/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-41-SqlQuery()-method.aspx

I'd really recommend you go with ADO.NET if you need DataTable.

Answer (score 4):

By the rule, you shouldn't use a DataSet inside a EF application. But, if you really need to (for instance, to feed a report), that solution should work (it's EF 6 code):

```
    DataSet GetDataSet(string sql, CommandType commandType, Dictionary<string, Object> parameters)
    {
        // creates resulting dataset
        var result = new DataSet();

        // creates a data access context (DbContext descendant)
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // creates a Command 
            var cmd = context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = commandType;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            // adds all parameters
            foreach (var pr in parameters)
            {
                var p = cmd.CreateParameter();
                p.ParameterName = pr.Key;
                p.Value = pr.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

            try
            {
                // executes
                context.Database.Connection.Open();
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                // loop through all resultsets (considering that it's possible to have more than one)
                do
                {
                    // loads the DataTable (schema will be fetch automatically)
                    var tb = new DataTable();
                    tb.Load(reader);
                    result.Tables.Add(tb);

                } while (!reader.IsClosed);
            }
            finally
            {
                // closes the connection
                context.Database.Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        // returns the DataSet
        return result;
    }
```