# Linq query to execute stored procedure with return type as DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get result as `DataTable` from a stored procedure using a Linq query. Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
_dbContext.Database.Sqlquery<DataTable>("dbo.uspGetOrdersDetails @orderID", orderParam);
```

but the result is empty

[image: Screenshot with return type as DataTable]

If I keep as viewmodel, then I am able to get the data

[image]

Just want to know that, is it possible with datatable.

Answer (score 1):

EntityFramework or LinqToSql doesn't support this out of the box. Instead, you can use the connection of your context and fill your DataTable using Ado.Net. You can find a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23698279/2045559). You can convert the solution provided in that answer to an extension method. A simple implementation:

```
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ExecuteQuery(this DbContext db, string commandText, CommandType commandType, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        var conn = db.Database.Connection;
        try
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandType = commandType;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(reader);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) 
                conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```